# Sub-sample shapefile coordinates of shapely polygon

Tags: python, shapely

I have a standard shapefile which has a column called `geometry`. This column contains a shapely `Polygon` object which is essentially a list of paired latitudes and longitudes that trace an object (e.g. the border of a country). The shapes are very complex/detailed, meaning that they have many points and are thus hard to plot. Is there a way to intelligently sub-sample the points in each polygon (e.g. taking only 1% of the points) in python.

I use the word intelligently because I need to ensure a few things:

1. The first and last point in the polygon must be the same (so that the shape reconnects to itself
2. If I have two polygons that share a points (e.g. when two countries share a border), there should be minimal overlap between the boundaries after sub-sampling.

An example of a piece of software that does this is https://mapshaper.org/. I want to do the same thing as their "simplify" tool, but in python.